# How to add a non-standard background to the MPAndroidChart library chart

Tags: background, mpandroidchart

I'm using a scatter plot where I want to use the background (image or programmatically) to immediately see which areas the dots are in.

[image]

I have not been able to find solutions to this problem.

How to do it?

**upd:** I used a combination chart where I plotted the curves using a line graph and the data is a dot graph.

What don't I like? In the legend, I need to hide the curve data. It is necessary to hide the points on the curves. I also need to make sure that the curves do not react to touch.

The dots should stand out, respond to touch and be displayed in symbols.

[image]

Is there a better solution?

**upd2:**

It is possible to hide the point value using

```
lineDataSet.setDrawValues(false)
```

It is possible to hide a point using

```
lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(false)
```

While I'm trying to remove the curve mark from the legend

**upd 3:**

To edit the legend, use the code below:

```
        val ccLegendEntries = arrayOf(
            combinedChartLegend.entries[4],
            combinedChartLegend.entries[5],
            combinedChartLegend.entries[6]
        )
        combinedChartLegend.setCustom(ccLegendEntries)
```

In general, the problem has been solved. But I do not know how to prohibit the selection of a point on curves and leave it for a point graph when combinedChart.setTouchEnabled(true)

It would also be good to understand how to paint over areas not from the coordinate axes.

Comment: I believe you can set "highlight enabled" on each data set individually. You should be able to disable it for the guide lines, while keeping it on for the main points.